# Python text game, where does this None come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nonetype

I'm trying to make a text based game, and, to make sure it fits in the screen and doesn't look too bad, I made this little function using the **Fill** method from **Wrapper**.

```
def reescalate_text(string):
     str = fill(string, width=110)
     return str
```

Now, this works perfectly, but for dialogues I have this other function:

```
def dialogue(text):
    text = fill(text, width=80)
    for i in text:
         sys.stdout.write(i)
         sys.stdout.flush()
         time.sleep(0.03)
         if i == ',':
             time.sleep(0.07)
         elif i == '.':
             time.sleep(0.42)
         elif i == '?':
             time.sleep(0.42)
         elif i == '!':
             time.sleep(0.62)
```

Just passing descriptions and stuff works great, but when I try to send a dialogue, it prints something like:

*Hey, you! You're finally awake. You were trying to cross the border, right?None*

I send the text to both functions like:

```
print(reescalate_text('You wake up in a cart, hands tied'))
print()
print(dialogue('Hey, you! You're finally awake. You were trying to cross the border, right?'))
```

I'm not sure where the None is coming from. I'm guessing that Fill is passing something at the end of *text* and stdout.write is writing it, but I'm a noob at programming in general and at Python in particular, so I'm completely lost.

*As a side note, I'm passing "." and "?" in different elifs instead of writing it like:*

```
if i == '.' or '?':
```

*because the sleep seems to take too much time*

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `if i == '.' or '?':` should be `if i == '.' or i == '?':`, or `if i in '.?':`.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from `print`ing the return value of `dialogue`. Since `dialogue` does not explicitly `return` anything, the return value is implicitly `None`.

The `dialogue` function already writes to `sys.stdout`, so you don't need to `print` anything; just call it like this:

```
dialogue('Hey, you! You're finally awake. You were trying to cross the border, right?')
```

The one thing `print` was doing for you is to write a newline. You will need to add that at the end of the `dialogue` function:

```
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```